# Autoscroll Datagrid in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any way to scroll Datagrid on timer basis.

Let say there are plenty of records which can not be shown in one screen. And the screen is showing the first 10 records. An auto scroll should start after 5 seconds and bring up the next 10 records. Then again after 5 seconds the other 10 records and so on. A kind slide show effect.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try looking up Timer.  You can set both the vertical and horizontal scroll positions of a Datagrid with the .verticalScrollBarPosition method.